# Calculating minimum length among the lists inside a list

Tags: python, list

```
a=[[1,0,1,2,1,1,1,3111111],[31,1,4,51,1,1,1],[1,1,6,7,8]]
print min(a[0],a[1],a[2])
```

The following code returns the `[1, 0, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 3111111]`. Not sure what is the default key and according to what logic is it returned?

Plus I was actually trying to find the minimum length out of these lists within a list.

I wrote this `min(len(a[0]),len(a[1]),len(a[2]))`. Can this be made any better?

Comment: Lists are sorted according to their contents, index by index; comparing `a[0]` and `a[1]` comes down to `1` < `31`, and for `a[0]` and `a[2]` it's `0` < `1` (second index).

Comment: Ok. so you mean to say kind of alphabetical like sorting?

Comment: It's [lexicographical order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order). So, yes, like alphabetical sorting, but generalized out to ordered sequences.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, you can use `map` to iterate over the inner lists to create a list of lengths, then get the minimum with `min`:

```
>>> a=[[1,0,1,2,1,1,1,3111111],[31,1,4,51,1,1,1],[1,1,6,7,8]]
>>> min(map(len, a))
 5
```

Comment: Solves my problem, but what about 1st question?

Answer (score 20):

A few options:

```
a = [[1,0,1,2,1,1,1,3111111], [31,1,4,51,1,1,1], [1,1,6,7,8]]

print(min(a, key=len))
# [1, 1, 6, 7, 8]

print(len(min(a, key=len)))
# 5

print(min(map(len, a)))
# 5
```

Comment: Thanks. Any idea about the 1st question?

Comment: I think it sorts by first element, then second element, and so on.

Comment: The last one is more efficient than the second one; the second calls `len()` N+1 times, the last one only N times.

Comment: @MartijnPieters my mistake, I just assumed the second was more efficient as it's slightly faster in python 2. It turns out to be slower in python 3 though.

Comment: How did you measure that? Using `timeit`?

Comment: @MartijnPieters yeah. Is `timeit` suitable for this kind of timing?

Comment: @grc: No, `timeit` is the correct tool to use for measuring this.

Answer (score 2):

You could write it as a loop to create a list instead of having to type it always:

```
min([len(x) for x in a])
```

This would acomplish what you want no matter how many lists are inside **a**

Comment: Why use a list comprehension when a generator expression is enough? `min(len(x) for x in a)`. But in that case a simple `map()` call is going to be faster still: `min(map(len, a))`.