# Can I quickly get the minimum length of the most inner sub-lists within a list in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, variable-length

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18741633/calculating-minimum-length-among-the-lists-inside-a-list) shows how to get the minimum length of first-level inner lists.

How can I return `4` for this list
`b=[[1,0,1,2,1,1,1,3111111,[1,1,6,7]],[31,1,4,51,1,1,1],[1,1,6,7,8]]`
as `[1,1,6,7]` only has 4 elements.

I can run a for-loop to get it. But can it be simpler?

I mean "the length of the shortest list that is at the same depth as the deepest list".

Comment: Try it yourself first, then ask if you got trouble or error. Good luck!

Comment: When you say "minimum length of the most inner sub-lists", do you mean "the length of the shortest list that is at the same depth as the deepest list"? Or just "the length of the shortest list contained within the given list"?

Comment: But your outer-list at the same level as other list is `[1,0,1,2,1,1,1,3111111,[1,1,6,7]]` of which `[1,1,6,7]` is the sublist. Do you still want to consider it's length? As per this logic I think your answer should be 0, because other list aren't having nested list.

Comment: I mean the deepest list.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

v1, minimum length at any depth:

```
>>> b = [[1,0,1,2,1,1,1,3111111,[1,1,6,7]],[31,1,4,51,1,1,1],[1,1,6,7,8]]
>>> def lists_in(L):
...     for element in L:
...         if isinstance(element, list):
...             yield element
...             yield from lists_in(element)
...             
>>> min(lists_in(b), key=len)
[1, 1, 6, 7]
>>> len(min(lists_in(b), key=len))
4
```

---

v2, with new requirement "the length of the shortest list that is at the same depth as the deepest list":

```
>>> def depths_and_lengths(L, depth=0):
...     for element in L:
...         if isinstance(element, list):
...             yield (depth, len(element))
...             yield from depths_and_lengths(element, depth-1)
...             
...             
>>> min(depths_and_lengths(b))[1]
4
>>> min(depths_and_lengths([[[1, 2]]]))[1]    # Stefan Pochmann example
2
```

Comment: I don't think this computes "the length of the shortest list that is at the same depth as the deepest list"

Comment: For `[[[1, 2]]]` this reports `1`, even though the only most inner list is `[1, 2]`, which has length `2`.

Comment: Geeze guys, that vague requirement was just edited in 2 minutes ago, after I posted this answer.

Comment: @wim Not true. It was in the title the whole time. (At least as far as I can tell, looking at the edit history)

Comment: Tough crowd @wim

Comment: @BradSolomon Says the guy who quotes "Beware of the man who won't be bothered with details" on his profile :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a bad answer:

```
def mpr(x, inital=[]):
    if isinstance(x, list):
        inital.append(len(x))
        map(lambda x: mpr(x, inital), x)
    return inital
```

`mpr(b)` -> [3, 9, 4, 7, 5]